# What is in `C:\ccmcache`?

Tags: windows-7

It seems as if it were some type of windows system file backup, although I am not sure. Anyways, system backup data (at least the restore points) are in `C:\System Volume Information`, AFAIK. What is in this `C:\ccmcache` folder? Is it safe to simply delete that?

Comment: There is no such folder by default in Windows. It is probably part of a software package you installed.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The `ccmcache` folder is used by System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM) client. This is where files downloaded by SCCM are stored. SCCM is an enterprise software management system used in many Windows environment, and provides operating system and software deployment services, remote management, reporting services, etc. You will typically only find this folder on systems in a managed enterprise environment.

SCCM caches files used for software deployment in the `ccmcache` folder. This may include software packages which are automatically installed on your machine, some types of software updates, etc. Files are *not* automatically removed from the `ccmcache` folder after they are used, but they are marked as being eligible for deletion. You should not manually delete files in this folder as you may accidentally delete something which has not been used yet. You should definitely not remove the folder altogether, as this would break SCCM and you would cease to automatically receive software packages from your network administrator.

You should be able to reduce the size of this folder using the ConfigMgr Control Panel. This will require local administrator privileges. To do this:

- Open "Configuration Manager Properties" in the control panel. You may need to change the control panel to "icon view" instead of "category view".
- Go to the "cache" tab
- Click "Configure Settings" and acknowledge the UAC Prompt if prompted
- The "Delete Files" button should become available. Click this button to clear files. It will automatically keep any files which should not be deleted.

Comment: @Vicky: You need to be logged into your computer as an administrator to be able to configure this option.  Also, your organization may have this option locked down via group policy. I would recommend you talk to your IT department.

Comment: Is there a way to write a script, executing this command?

Comment: Cleaning that folder is like getting an extra hd ! :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the 'icon' instead of 'category' view tip! I also learned the direct command for this is Start>> Run: `control smscfgrc` (via http://www.chrisnackers.com/2013/06/21/opening-the-configuration-manager-control-panel-icon-windows-8-frustrations-solved/)